# Is it possible to write a failable string composer in Swift?

Tags: swift, string, option-type

If I have this code:

```
let a : Int? = 10;
let b : String? = "Apples";
let result = "We have \(a) of \(b)";
// result will be "We have Optional(10) of Optional(Apples)"
```

I can remove the optionals by adding default value:

```
let result = "We have \(a ?? 0) of \(b ?? "")";
// result will be "We have 10 of Apples"
```

But what if I want that if any of the optionals in the string is nil, then the string result is nil altogether?

```
let a : Int? = nil;
let b : String? = "Apples";
let result = "We have \(a) of \(b)";
// result will be nil
```

So I can write like this:

```
let a : Int? = nil;
let b : String? = "Apples";
if let result = "We have \(a) of \(b)" { self.process(result); }
```

EDIT:

What I'm actually trying to achieve is like this:

```
func process (_ s: String?) {
    guard let s = s else { return; }
    print (s);
}

let a : Int? = nil;
let b : String? = "Apples";
let result = "We have \(a) of \(b)";
self.process (result);
```

Thanks.

Comment: The first think you should learn in Swift is that you don't need to add `;` all over your code

Comment: @LeoDabus I know. But I'm switching development between legacy Obj C and Swift every now and then, so I don't want to risk losing my auto-`;` habit. And I think code concluded with `;` is neater. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`map`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1539476-map)/[`flatMap`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1540500-flatmap) method of `Optional`:

```
let a : Int? = nil
let b : String? = "Apples"

let result = a.flatMap { a in b.map { b in
    "We have \(a) of \(b)"
} }
```

The result is a (constant) `String?`. It is `nil` if any of `a` or `b` is `nil`, and the string with the unwrapped values otherwise.

Comment: Why not map in both of them?

Comment: @LeoDabus: The outer a.flatMap returns nil if a==nil *or* if the inner b.map returns nil. With map+map the return type would be a "double optional" String?? – Therefore you need flatMap for all except the innermost closure.

Comment: This is very interesting. This still allows for optional chaining, even though the code probably longer than I would prefer. But a good workaround nonetheless!

Comment: @MartinR never thought about this possibility

Answer (score 0):

You can simply declare another optional variable, and set it **ONLY** if all your required conditions are met (the other 2 variables being not null).

(Since your process function already handles optional strings correctly)

```
func process (_ s: String?) {
    guard let s = s else { return; }
    print (s);
}

let a : Int? = nil;
let b : String? = "Apples";
var result : String?

if let a = a, let b = b {
  result = "We have \(a) of \(b)" 
}

self.process (result);
```

Comment: I know about this. The problem is this breaks the optional chaining process I'm so fond of swift. With supposed optional chaining at my code above, there are so much code cut down, and the code is (arguably) more readable. Sometimes I also do like this: `let result = "a-b-c-d-e".components(separatedBy: "-");` This cannot be done in just one line if using your method, and I actually has to create additional variables just to check about that.

Comment: And if I'm going down your route, I actually don't need to make the parameter in `process` as String optional. But what if the process also returns String optional? I can do like this: `if let data = self.process("We have \(a) of \(b)") { doSomething(result); }"` in this scenario, I can pass all the optionality down to the very last point where I actually need to check whether it's optional or not, which is when I need to pass something that is not optional to `doSomething()`.